# php mysql display table

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner and somehow made to get the query (php & Mysql) I want and using echo i got the output as few lines without difficulty. But now I want the output inside the cell of a table. I tried something like this:

This does not work:

```
<tr>
<th>subject</th>
<th>grade</th>
</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$Row['name1']."</td>;
  echo "<td>".$Row['subject1'].</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Whereas this work:

```
       echo $line['name1']."<tr></td>"."";
       echo $line['subject1']."<tr></td>"."";
```

The echo $line statement echoes the value of name1 and subject1 without any difficulty. but the echo Row is not showing the output. As my data has only one row I dont have to use any loop. I actually want two fields in first row (name1 and subject1) and then in next row the fields of name2 and subject2 and till name7, subject7. It looks like the format inside the table is wrong. Could someone help me plz?

Comment: please show your full code?

Comment: Did you assign the results to $line or to $Row?

Comment: Why don't you try using `$line` instead of `$Row` in the case where it's not working

Answer (score 0):

First of all replace

```
echo "<td>".$Row['name1']."</td>;
```

with

```
echo "<td>".$Row['name1']."</td>";
```

you are missing (") at the end before (;)

Answer (score 0):

Updated with the missing table tag. Try this

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>subject</th>';
echo '<th>grade</th>';
echo '</tr>';
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$Row['name1']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$Row['subject1']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand the current answers, I'd suggest you use a single echo and *concatenate* the strings or even better, just use *one single string* and concatenate only the *necessary* variables:

```php
<?php
    echo '
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>subject</th>
            <th>grade</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>'.$Row['name1'].'</td>
            <td>'.$Row['subject1'].'</td>
        </tr>
    </table>';  
?>
```

This of course works better if the amount of PHP code is greater than the amount of HTML code. But if you were to write more HTML than PHP, it'd make more sense to just open and close `<?php?>` tags and echoing the variable you want.

I used an answer instead of a comment for the sake of the example. Feel free to try this approach when you are dealing with several html elements and need to *insert* your values within them.

Comment: Why not writing html directly, and just interpolate the few php parts?

Comment: @DamienPirsy It would make more sense to do what you suggest, the code I suggested was only to follow the OP's original design scheme. And of course it depends on the amount of code of each language that is going to be used, I'm goind to specify that on my answer, thanks.